# Coroutines in Visual C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I am trying to implement Coroutine library with Visual C++ however I noticed that there a couple of functions missing such as:

```
sigsetjmp, siglongjmp, setcontext, getcontext, swapcontext, longjmp, setjmp
```

I've looked through the Windows SDK and there is no functions like these that are exported. I know that there are Fiber functions for this but I would like a faster approach implemented using assembly. AFAIK they are in `glibc` but not in `msvcrt`.

Why are these functions missing?

Comment: Those aren't "missing," they're just part of the Unix platform standard. If you Google around you can probably find the Win32 equivalents.

Comment: Some functions are handled inline by the compiler - you won't find them searching extern symbols in SDK dlls/libs.  For example, `longjmp` and `setjmp` are available in VisualC++ as documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ye15wsy.aspx).

Comment: Windows already has a its own solution for this called [Fibers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682661%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: `I know that there are Fiber functions for this but I would like a faster approach implemented using assembly` How do you think fibers are implemented - rope and pulley? Also, how come you don't have the same objection to using library functions on Linux?

Comment: @TonyD Be very careful with `setjmp` and `longjmp` in a C++ program - they'll trigger undefined behavior given half a chance. "**18.10/4** The function signature `longjmp(jmp_buf jbuf, int val)` has more restricted behavior in this International Standard. A `setjmp`/`longjmp` call pair has undefined behavior if replacing the `setjmp` and `longjmp` by `catch` and `throw` would invoke any non-trivial destructors for any automatic objects."

Comment: MSVC2015 has C++ native coroutines (function level instead of stack level too).  Considered that?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I guess you meant to address that to user4855729? I've just answered a question about their availability - not making any recommendation.